# Suppose 'a' be a real constant. Then find the number of roots of $f(x)=(\frac{1}{x})-(\frac{1}{x})^3-a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can not think how to start with the problem. Please give the solution to this.

$f(x)=(\frac{1}{x})-(\frac{1}{x})^3-a$?

---

Comment: Set equal to zero, and multiply by x³

Comment: By "solution" do you mean "root"?

Comment: This can be solved trigonometrically, but I have deleted my answer until more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is shown. Providing context not only assures that we are not simply doing someone's homework for them, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=1/x$ so that the equation is

$$t^3-t=a.$$

By the sudy of variations of $t^3-t$, we see that this function is growing from $(-\infty,-\infty)$ up to $(-1/\sqrt3,2/3\sqrt3)$, then decreasing to $(1/\sqrt3,-2/3\sqrt3)$, and increasing again.

We conclude that the numbers of intersections with the horizontal $y=a$ is $3$ for $a$ in $(-1/\sqrt3,1/\sqrt3)$ and $1$ elsewhere.

Comment: For two values of $a$ there must exist only two solutions ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: as these cases have null measure, I was too lazy to mention them. :) Should I add "and $2$ between" ?

Comment: I doubt that a college math teacher will like the null measure argument joke when his student tells him. No points for that.

Comment: @Taamer: I feel sorry for you.

Comment: Wow, you can't take any piece of criticism without going ad hominem? I think that your solution does not _teach_ anything to the poster. When you teach maths, you have to adapt the hint to the student so he can start and make it by himself. My 0.02btc.

Comment: @Taamer: I mean it, I feel sorry for you to take things so seriously.

Comment: Don't worry, I can be a fun person, too. When we meet, share a drink and have a good conversation in real life. Thanks for caring about me!

Answer (score 0):

Hints to start:

> Write down for which values of x, f(x) is defined.
>
> Then, rewrite $f(x)$ by putting all the terms in a single fraction : $f(x)=\frac{n(x)}{d(x)}$

Now, when f(x) is defined, solving for f(x)=0 is equivalent for solving

> $n(x) = 0$

Now, the problem is simpler : find the roots of n(x).

**Hope this helps!**